# single icalendar rule for 1st weekday of multiple months every year?

Tags: icalendar

Is it possible to specify an event to occur on the 1st weekday of multiple months every year in a single RRULE? Using January and June as a test case, my initial attempt was:

```
FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR;BYMONTH=1,6;BYSETPOS=1
```

but BYSETPOS reduces the set down to January only. I think splitting it out into multiple rrules would work, but it would greatly increase the complexity of this area of my app so I was hoping for one rrule with a yearly freq.

Thanks!

Comment: reduce `freq` to monthly and add `interval` with a value of 6 (every six months... sorry for the confusion (I think I understand your Q now)

Comment: Thanks blurfus, but I don't think a monthly freq combined with an interval would work. The UI supports selecting an arbitrary number of months...I came up with January and June for simplicity. I'll update the question.

Comment: how about `FREQ=MONTHLY;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR;BYSETPOS=1;BYMONTH=<SELECTED_MONTHS_FROM_UI>` ? (order of options is different)

Comment: Yes, I think that would work. I was hoping to keep the freq yearly so the UI doesn't reconfigure itself, but I think I can work around that.  Thanks blurfus. Can you change this to an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: yeah! I understand... I don't see another way around it right now... btw, thanks

Comment: is the answer not acceptable anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
FREQ=MONTHLY;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR;BYSETPOS=1;BYMONTH=<SELECTED_MONTHS_FROM_UI>
```

Please note the order of options is different.

Comment: Not a valid answer anymore?

Comment: Thought it was...but it breaks when you add in an interval because the freq changes to monthly.

Comment: I looked at your other question... I see the other issue but this was the correct answer to the question asked.  this is not the answer to the other new question.  Seems unfair

Comment: You are right blurfus. I did not factor interval into this question so your answer was correct with the information I provided. I am going to mark this as correct. Thank you for helping me!

Comment: thanks for seeing my pov - I will try to see if I can provide any help with the new question