# iCalendar recurrence rule for event that occurs every two years in multiple months on first weekend day

Tags: icalendar

Is it possible to specify an event to occur on the 1st weekend day of multiple months every 2 years in a single RRULE? Using February and September as a test case, my first thought was:

```
FREQ=YEARLY;DTSTART=20140320T070000Z;INTERVAL=2;BYSETPOS=1;BYMONTH=2,9;BYDAY=SA,SU
```

but BYSETPOS reduces the set down to February only. I thought changing the freq to monthly would do the trick after I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22467453/single-icalendar-rule-for-1st-weekday-of-multiple-months-every-year), but applying an interval of 2 for every other year messes things up because the interval is applied to a monthly freq instead of a yearly freq.

I made this a new question because I did not include interval in my original question.

I think splitting this into multiple rrules would work, but it would greatly increase the complexity of this area of my app so I was hoping for a single rrule with a **yearly** freq.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try this one:  `FREQ=YEARLY;DTSTART=20140320T070000Z;INTERVAL=2;BYMONTH=2,9;BYDAY=SA,SU;BYSETPOS=1` ? (different order of `BYSETPOS`)

Comment: Digging into this a little more...I don't think the order of the string tokens matters. The RFC (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545.txt) lists the order the byxxx rules should be evaluated in: 

If multiple BYxxx rule parts are specified, then after evaluating
the specified FREQ and INTERVAL rule parts, the BYxxx rule parts
are applied to the current set of evaluated occurrences in the
following order: BYMONTH, BYWEEKNO, BYYEARDAY, BYMONTHDAY, BYDAY,then COUNT and UNTIL are evaluated.


Testing it at  http://jkbr.github.io/rrule/ doesn't show a change either.

Comment: I tried the tool you linked to and it lead me to this: `FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=2;BYMONTH=2,9;BYDAY=+1SA,+1SU` -> only issue is that returns both weekend days (from the first weekend) instead of either sat or sun...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW, and since you mention it as a potential workaround, RFC5545 has removed the ability to have multiple RRULE property in a single VEVENT/VTODO (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.6.1). It was there in RFC2445.

Then, unless someone finds a very elegant and simple solution, you may be left with something that is so convoluted that most clients will barf on it (don't know how interoperability is important to you).

This leaves you with 2 choices I think:

- either use 2 different events (maybe linked with a [RELATED-TO](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.4.5) property)
- or, if you can bound the event to a certain number of instances, represent it as a set of RDATE (or RRULE + RDATE, or RRULE + EXDATE, etc...).

Comment: Thanks arnaudq. I don't see a better way either. This is really an edge-case anyway and seems more trouble than its worth so I think I'll just disallow it.

Answer (score 0):

Adding BYSETPOS like this may work as you intend:

```
FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=2;BYMONTH=2,9;BYDAY=+1SA,+1SU;BYSETPOS=1,3
```

Comment: Also, for every month selected, you need to add an odd number to the `BYSETPOS` sequence. i.e. if you had 3 months selected, you need to add `1, 3, 5` - if you had 4 months selected: `1,3,5,7` and so on...

Comment: BYDAY=+1SA with FREQ=YEARLY will lead to the first Saturday of the year... see RFC5545 `Each BYDAY value can also be preceded by a positive (+n) or negative (-n) integer.  If present, this indicates the nth occurrence of a specific day within the MONTHLY or YEARLY "RRULE".`

Comment: @oberron I tested the rule here: http://jkbr.github.io/rrule and it seemed to work (you can copy+paste it into RRULE String tab) - 

Also you are completing ignoring the other parameters I included in your commentary. But, don't believe me, try it yourself before voting me down - thx

Comment: my mistake indeed i was too quick as indeed the byday only applies to bymonth as per RFC5545 wich overides my previous extract `example of evaluating multiple BYxxx rule parts.` I'll fix the down-vote as soon as the timer expires

Comment: Thanks for considering my POV;

Answer (score 0):

what you could try is to take advantage of the fact that bysetpos allows you to select within the year the selected instances of your rule, then you could limit the number of instances to the first week of the month (by setting the days of the month to the first 6 ones) to avoid the cases where month have more or less weeks, which then allows you to select the first and third instance in your year.

Which then gives:

`DTSTART:20140320T060000Z
FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=2;WKST=MO;BYSETPOS=1,3;BYMONTH=2,9;BYMONTHDAY=1,2,3,4,5,6,7;BYDAY=SA,SU`

which will be:

```
Sat 2014/Sept/6
Sat 2016/Feb/6
Sat 2016/Sep/3
...
Sun 2024/Sep/1
```

this was verified with dateutil-python and http://jkbr.github.io/,